# FFT/FHT - Specific frequency range - Arduino

Tags: resize, arduino, fft, spectrum

So I'm working on a project where I need to analyze audio with an Arduino.

Basically it's a light organ, and I need to do some Beat Detection
in order to match the LEDs to shift color based on the tempo of the song.

I have successfully managed to get the FFT and FHT library from Open Music Labs
to work with my arduino, but the lower end of the spectrum seems to be very
narrow if terms of resolution.

I have tried to find information of how to broaden the resolution in that area,
but with no success.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: make a list frequencies you want to sample and do DFFT for just them ...